Audio API Not Playing on Mobile Devices in Next.js Application
I'm working on a Next.js application that includes playing audio using the HTML5 Audio API. It works perfectly on desktop browsers, but I'm encountering issues when trying to play audio on mobile devices (both iOS and Android). The audio does not play, and there are no error messages in the console.
Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:
import { useEffect } from "react"

const AudioPlayer = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const audio = new Audio("/path/to/audio/file.mp3")
    audio.play().catch(error => {
      console.error("Error playing audio:", error)
    });
  }, []);
  return <div>Audio Player</div>
};

export default AudioPlayer

I've tried the following solutions without success:

Ensuring the audio file path is correct.
Testing different audio formats (MP3, WAV).
Using user interaction to trigger the audio play (e.g., button click).
Checking for mobile-specific restrictions or permissions.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this?
Thanks in advance!

do you wait long enough for the audio file to be "downloaded"/ready, use the onload event for the audio object to init the play function

yes but i don't hear any audio in mobile device but in desktop everything is okey

which mobile device?

IOS (IPhone 14 Pro Max)  Safari, Android(Samsung s21 ultra)  Chrome

The audio file needs to be hosted on an HTTPS url/location inorder to play on mobile.

Yes, I tested this way, but it still doesn't work.

Could you test this.
import { useState } from "react";

const AudioPlayer = () => {
  const [audio] = useState(new Audio("/path/to/audio/file.mp3"));

  const playAudio = () => {
    audio.play().catch(error => {
      console.error("Error playing audio:", error);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={playAudio}>Play Audio</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AudioPlayer;

